# Dual boot windows 7 and windows 10

Tags: windows, boot, mbr, gpt

Is possible to do a dual boot with windiws 10 and windows 7?I am asking this because widows 10 utilizes gpt partition instead windows 7 utilizes mbr partition.

Answer (score 1):

> I am asking this because windows 10 utilizes GPT partition instead
>   windows 7 utilizes MBR partition.

Close, but not quite.

Both Windows 7 and windows 10 can use both MBR partitioned harddisks as well from GPT partitioned harddisks.

It is just that the default in the windows 7 era was MBR.  But you can install windows 7 on a moderm UEFI system on a GPT partitioned harddisk.

Vice versa, windows 10 runs fine in UEFI systems with GPT partitioned harddisks (I am typing on sunch a machine) as well in MBR mode (My feb 2009 laptop with only BIOS firmware was recently upgraded to windows 10).

Having said that, you probably want to install both systems in the same way. If at all possible both with regular UEFI firmware (no CSM enabled), GPT partitioned harddisks and for windows 7 the graphics mode in legacy (int 10) mode.

Alternatively, install both in MBR mode. It just works.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I want to highlight the fact that Windows ties boot mode and partition table type pretty tightly: In a BIOS-mode boot, MBR is used; and in an EFI/UEFI-mode boot, GPT is used. It's the boot mode of the installation medium that determines the partition table type that the installer will create if the disk is blank. If you boot the Windows installer and it sees an existing partition table of the wrong type (as it might if you installed another Windows version in the other mode), the installer will complain about the partition table type.

Comment: Correct. Which is why you need to boot & install both in UEFI-mode or in BIOS/EFI_with_CSM_used-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Someone more qualified on the Windows bootloader will probably supply a better answer than this but it should be possible.

Get both your 7 and 10 installs on different partitions on your system and run the Linux boot repair CD.

It will sniff the partitions on the system and then spam GRUB into the boot sector of all of them and will have options to boot either.

Comment: Yes but how windows 7 will boot if the hard disk is partitioned with gpt?

Comment: As I said before, I'm not a Windows bootloader expert. Having skimmed the MS knowledgebase about this, GPT volumes have a protective MBR section. I would suspect that in the configuration I discussed above, GRUB would put itself in the MBR of the disk and then fire the needed parts of the OS. I do know that the Linux boot repair CD has got me to boot both 7/Linux and 10/Linux configs when the Windows bootloader has failed. You should now try and experiment with configurations and possibly answer your own question.

Comment: i need an explanation, graphic and lotsa handholding!!!! How  do  i install Win7 on a win 10+ 8 dual booted system? I got four partitions